# Non convex quadratic optimization solvers in python

Tags: python, optimization, non-convex

Let me start saying that I am by no means expert in optimization, so any suggestion would be greatly appreciated. I have a non-convex quadratic optimization problem for which I need a solver. I myself am used to working with the modelling language `CVXPY`, using some of the default solvers there (`ECOS`, `CVXOPT`,...) so something similar to it would be great. I cannot use `cvxpy` on this problem because it is only suitable for convex optimization problems.

After googling, I saw some people recommending `Pyomo`, saying it could deal with non convex problems, but my problem requires matrix algebra, and as far as I know, `Pyomo` does not include matrix algebra capabilities. So I would require a non convex modeling language or solver for non convex quadratic problems.

The type of problem I am actually interested in solving has the following structure:

[image]

where `w`is the vector variable to be optimized, `X`is a known data matrix and `t`is a prespecified parameter value.

Comment: Pyomo+Couenne can handle this (I don't understand your point that it would need matrix algebra -- the notation is different but it surely can express this problem quite easily). Also, Gurobi can solve nonconvex quadratic problems.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Having no matrix algebra makes the process of changing the objectvie function quite cumbersome. I can code in pyomo the  above function, but if instead of  (X.T@X) I had to maximize over (say) (Y.T@X.T)@(X@Y) I would need to redefine the whole equation in pyomo. This process is much simpler using matrix algebra.I will have a look into Gurobi.